# jQuery - Replace a word in a child div if parent div contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is change a specific word in a div I've added if the parent div contains a specific word;

```
<p class="days">Stock, 1 piece remaining.</p>
```

I have to add an additional workaround to add another div for more information using the prepend function:

```
$(".days").append('<div class="daysAddiontalInfo">Explaination of stock 1 piece</div>');
```

I'd like the following; if my parent div (.days) contains the number 1 - I need it to show 1 piece, but if it contains the number 2,3,4 or 5 I need it to show 2,3,4 or 5 pieces.

I got no idea how to expand the code to do this specific task.

Thanks in advance for your time and feedback!

Comment: You might want to look up https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example solution:

```
var $days = $(".days");
var pieces = $days.text().match(/\d/);

$days.append('<div class="daysAddiontalInfo">Explaination of stock '+pieces+' piece</div>');
```

And a working code: http://jsfiddle.net/367vvq1a/

Also, to take a plural form into consideration - and account for having more than one `.days` element - you can do it like this:

```
$(".days").each(function () {
    var piecesMatch = $(this).text().match(/\d+/);
    if (piecesMatch) {
        var piecesCount = parseInt(piecesMatch[0]);
        var piecesText = piecesCount + ((piecesCount > 1) ? ' pieces' : ' piece');
        $(this).append('<div class="daysAddiontalInfo">Explaination of stock '+piecesText+'</div>');
    }
});
```

And here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p02wvtvs/1/

Comment: That plural form looks promising, but it doesn't change the value from piece to pieces when the number is greater than 1? it keeps showing piece no matter what number is in the .days paragraph?

Comment: I've made a little fix (it was matching only one digit instead of whole number, so if given e.g. 17 it was treating it as a 1 ;) ) and prepared a working code, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/p02wvtvs/.

Comment: @user3587168 I have also made an update to account to having more than one `.days` element

Comment: @user3587168 sure ;) Please accept the answer if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure it will be a number then you can use

```
var number = parseInt($(".days").text());
$(".days").append('<div class="daysAddiontalInfo">Explaination of stock "+ number +" piece</div>');
```

otherwise you can put specific word in `span` and get its value

```
<p class="days">Stock, <span>1</span> piece remaining.</p>
```

and in javascript

```
var word = $(".days span').text();
$(".days").append('<div class="daysAddiontalInfo">Explaination of stock "+ word +" piece</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a function to the `append()` method which will inspect the HTML of each `.days` element individually. From there you can use a regex to match on the `1 piece`, `2 pieces` etc strings, and return the new HTML to append. Try this:

```
$('.days').append(function(i, html) {
    var matches = /(\d pieces?)/gi.exec(html);
    return '<div class="daysAddiontalInfo">Explaination of stock ' + matches[0] + ' </div>';
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n20rpo36/)